# React Hooks "I am trying to use react hooks with checkbox toggle but its updating all checkboxes " using rendition

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I am trying to manage state with react hooks for my checkBOx toggle but I  am  failing to manage different state for different checkbox, with my code I am trying "ON" & "OFF" for toggle but when I am trying to toggle any checkbox its changing states for all of my checkboxes all at once.
following is my code  :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Box, Checkbox, Flex, Table, Txt } from 'rendition';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ControlContainer = styled(Box)`
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
`;

export const Devices = () => {
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);


function toggle(event) {
 return setChecked(event.target.checked ? setChecked(false) : setChecked(true));
}

const SAMPLE_DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Balcony',
    active: true,
    brightness: 50,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bedroom 01',
    active: false,
    brightness: 70,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Bedroom 02',
    active: false,
    brightness: 70,
  },
];

const columns = [

  {
    field: 'name',
    label: 'Room',
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'active',
    label: 'State',
    sortable: true,
    render() {
      return (
        <Flex>
          <Checkbox toggle checked={checked} onChange={toggle} mr={2} />
          <Txt ml={2}>{checked ? 'On' : 'Off'}</Txt>
        </Flex>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'brightness',
    label: 'Brightness',
    sortable: true,
    render(value) {
      return `${value}%`;
    },
  },
];
  return (
    <Flex flex='1' mt={4}>
      <Box flex='3' pl={3}>
        <Table
          flex='1'
          columns={columns}
          data={SAMPLE_DATA}
          rowKey='id'
          onRowClick={console.log}
        />
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

PS : Getting following warnings :

> Each child in a list should have a unique `key` prop.
>
> Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an 
>   `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be
>    mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Comment: did you check the console of the browser ? any warnings?

Comment: yes I am getting errors please check above

Comment: each child component should have a unique for the DOM manipulation, and more over there are lot of errors in your code. 1) why using render in `columns` array?

Comment: You only have a single state variable which is being used by all of the checkboxes, so when you call `setChecked(true)` anything referencing your `checked` state variable will also be set to true, therefore all of your checkboxes will update. You need seperate state variables per checkbox.

Comment: I think i found a solution thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after getting lots of suggestions and a downvote finally I got a solution.
It is divided into three parts.
first I passed `SAMPLE_DATA` as useState

```
const [data,setdata]=useState(SAMPLE_DATA)
```

Secondly, I made some changes in my checkbox by adding a check on the field : `row.active`

```
 <Flex>
      <Checkbox toggle 
                checked={row.active}  
                mr={2} id={`checkbox-${row.id}`} 
                data-rowid={row.id} 
                onChange={toggle}/>
      <Txt ml={2}> {row.active ? 'on' : 'off'} </Txt>
    </Flex>
```

at last, I altered my toggle function accordingly

```
const toggle=(event)=> {
let rowId = event.target.getAttribute('data-rowId')
let newData = data.map(item => {
  if(item.id == rowId) {
    item.active = event.target.checked
    }
  return item;
})
setdata(newData)
}
```

Thank you all for your valuable time and suggestions.`Topic Closed`